# Using Google API Java Client for Uploading Database to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: java, android, google-sheets, google-api-java-client

I wanted to get some feedback before I jumped into this. I am interested in making my Android Application upload my SQLite database to Google Spreadsheet. I have gotten some mixed feedback from several people so I wanted to make sure I am going in the right direction.

Should I use [Google API Java Client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/), or more specifically [Google Documents List API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/) to create a spreadsheet and then Google Spreadsheet API to add and edit data in the spreadsheet. Is this is the right approach for what I am doing? If so, are you aware of some useful sample code?

I would really appreciate someones guidance in this matter. If something in my question is unclear, please ask.

Cheers, 
George

Comment: Your question is not realyl clear. WHY do you want to store a "DATABASE" into a "SPREADSHEET"??? Does your database only contain one table? Google also has a "data API", I forgot how it is called, perhaps that is better suited?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to say TABLE. I am receiving data from bluetooth device and I am saving it in a table. I wanted to upload the table data to a Google Spreadsheet so that I could check it without being on my mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

do not use the Documents List API which is deprecated.

All the actions you list (create a spreadsheet and fill it in) can be realized with the [GData Spreadsheets API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?hl=fr#creating_a_spreadsheet). The documentation contains good examples in Java.

If you also want to share the spreadsheet or move it to a specific Drive folder, use the [Google Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-java).